# Linux Mint 18: Suspend only happens after unlock

Tags: laptop, linux-mint, systemd, suspend

I'm running Linux Mint 18 Cinnamon, I wanted to set it so that, when my laptop's lid is closed, it is suspended. Obviously, I set this in the power settings. However, what ends up happening is that the screen locks, but the laptop is not suspended. If I type in my password, and unlock the session, the machine is suspended, and it can be re-awoken as usual, although I do not have to unlock it.

If I run `systemctl suspend`, the same thing happens, however `sudo pm-suspend` works as expected.

If I edit /etc/systemd/logind.conf with respect to `HandleLidSwitch`, nothing changes.

As far as I can tell, I *think* this is something to do with the interaction between systemd and whatever Mint uses to deal with system suspension, but I'm a bit stuck.

Note: It worked as I expected in Mint 17 (that is, when the lid is closed, it suspends, and when I wake it, the session is locked).